# Counting duplications in a list analytically

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose I have the following list, 
$$l=\{\{a,b,c,d\},\{a,n,d\}\}$$
I go through each element and write the subsets of size two, namely: 
$$\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, d\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, d\}, \{c, 
  d\}, \{a, n\}, \{a, d\}, \{n, d\}\}$$
there are 9 elements in the newly formed list. This is because
$$\binom{4}{2}+\binom{3}{2}=6+3=9$$
as you can see $\{a,d\}$ is duplicated, because the letters $a$ and $d$ are in both elements of list $l$, I wonder if there is a way to account those duplications using binomial coefficients or other methods? In fact the list I want is: 
$$\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}, \{a, d\}, \{b, c\}, \{b, d\}, \{c, 
  d\}, \{a, n\}, \{n, d\}\}$$
which has 8 elements (simply by dropping the duplicates), I just do not know how to write this analytically to get 8.

Comment: Yes, there is and you've all but figured it out.  The $2$-subsets that are counted twice have both elements in the intersection, as you've said.  Can you write down the formula?

Answer (score 1):

You have $l = \{\{a, b, c, d\}, \{a, n, d\}\}$.  If we denote $\{a, b, c, d\}$ by $A$ and $\{a, n, d\}$ by $B$, then $A \cap B = \{a, d\}$.  The number of subsets of size $2$ that can be drawn from the list is 
$$\binom{|A|}{2} + \binom{|B|}{2} - \binom{|A \cap B|}{2} = \binom{4}{2} + \binom{3}{2} - \binom{2}{2} = 6 + 3 - 1 = 8$$